# How do I install jboss?

Tags: 10.10, jboss

I'm looking for a How-to for installing JBoss on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

check what's here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JBoss

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there currently isn't any good support for installing JBoss AS in Ubuntu using the repository. All of the existing packages only contain the `.jar` files and there isn't a package that will really install the server and let you run it.

Your best bet is to go to [jboss.org](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas) and download the application server from there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is too old, but I find this excelent tutorial for installing Jbos in a ubuntu server.

[Install JBoss 7.0.2 Application Server on Ubuntu 11.10 or Ubuntu 11.04 or Ubuntu 10.10 or Ubuntu 10.04 LTS](http://clean-clouds.com/2011/12/30/install-jboss-7-0-2-application-server-on-ubuntu-11-10-or-ubuntu-10-04-lts/)

and this

[Install JBoss 7 on an Ubuntu 11.10 server](http://dont-panic.eu/blogs/2012/mar/install-jboss-7-ubuntu-1110-server)